# The computed properties & struct in my case

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning Swift, I saw some code from a project like following:

```
struct ServiceType {
    init(_ value: UInt)
    var value: UInt
}
var External: ServiceType { get }
var Internal: ServiceType { get }
var Normal: ServiceType { get }
```

I understand that the above code created three **computed properties** `External`, `Internal` & `Normal` all with type `ServiceType`.

What I want to ask are:

1. Why the `struct` declaration declare a init() ? I didn't see this when I was reading a Swift programming book.
2. What does it mean to have an underscore `_` followed by a space before `value: UInt` in the `init(_ value: UInt)` ?
3. Is it so that struct has a `value` property by default in Swift? The above code just explicitly set the type of `value` to UInt?
4. What does the empty get mean in each property? What value it returns?
5. Does the OS randomly assign UInt value to each property's value?

Answer (score 2):

1.
A struct gets a default initializer if it doesn't provide one on its own:

```
struct ServiceType {
    var value: UInt
}

// default initialize with an specified parameter name "value" (called external name)
let service = ServiceType(value: 4)
```

In this case the struct provides an initializer so you don't get the default one.

2.
The underscore says that you don't have an external name:

```
let service = ServiceType(4)
```

Replacing the underscore with a different name the name is now the external name:

```
struct ServiceType {
    init(aval value: UInt)
    var value: UInt
}

let service = ServiceType(aval: 4)
```

3.
If I understand you right structs in general don't have a value property by default and in this case a `value` property is declared to be of type `Uint`. `var value = 0` would be inferred to be of type `Int`.

4.
If you have seen this code in a protocol `{ get }` means that it only returns a value and does not set one (`{ get set }`).

The return value of these computed properties are all of type `ServiceType`.

5.
In Swift you don't get default values for `Ints`, `Doubles`, ... as in other languages (mostly 0) except for `Optionals` which are `nil` by default. So you have to make sure that the value is initialized before using it otherwise the compiler will complain.

All of this gets pretty clear if you read the [initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) chapter of the Swift book.